# Is there an efficient way to append to an existing csv file without duplicates in R?

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, append, write.table

There is a data.frame appended to a existing file. When it is appended by write.table function, it might cause duplicated records into the file. Here is the sample code:

```
df1<-data.frame(name=c('a','b','c'), a=c(1,2,2))
write.csv(df1, "export.csv", row.names=FALSE, na="NA"); 

#"export.csv" keeps two copies of df1
write.table(df1,"export.csv", row.names=F,na="NA",append=T, quote= FALSE, sep=",", col.names=F);
```

So ideally the output file should only keep one copy of df1. But the write.table function doesn't have any parameter for duplicate check.

Thank you for any suggestion in advance.

Comment: Append in an R session using `rbind` and remove duplicates before writing your CSV?

Comment: @AnandaMahto Sorry my sample misleading. The first two commands create the test file. In my real code, df1 will not in memory if it is not read beforehand.

Comment: You could always do this outside of R. Append all your files and then use something like [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.0/) to process the CSV.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could read the data.frame from file, `rbind` it with the new data.frame and check for duplicate values. For writing efficiency, append only the non-duplicate rows.

If you came up with this question because you are working with big data sets and read/write time is of concern, take a look at `data.table` and `fread` packages.

```
# initial data.frame
df1<-data.frame(name=c('a','b','c'), a=c(1,2,2))
write.csv(df1, "export.csv", row.names=FALSE, na="NA")

# a new data.frame with a couple of duplicate rows
df2<-data.frame(name=c('a','b','c'), a=c(1,2,3))
dfRead<-read.csv("export.csv") # read the file
all<-rbind(dfRead, df2) # rbind both data.frames
# get only the non duplicate rows from the new data.frame
nonDuplicate <- all[!duplicated(all)&c(rep(FALSE, dim(dfRead)[1]), rep(TRUE, dim(df2)[1])), ]
# append the file with the non duplicate rows
write.table(nonDuplicate,"export.csv", row.names=F,na="NA",append=T, quote= FALSE, sep=",", col.names=F)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Is there any way to avoid read the existing file?

Comment: @YYY Yes. You can use `rbind` without importing or exporting files. It works on any two R objects with the same number of columns.

Comment: Sorry my sample misleading. The first two commands create the test file. In my real code, df1 will not in memory if it is not read beforehand.

Comment: @YYY Oh, I see. So you want to write new data to the csv without reading it in? Yea, you can do that too.

Comment: @Sirvydas Yes. How to do that w/o reading in it but w/ duplicate check.

Comment: @YYY I don't think you can do it without reading in the csv file as how would you do the duplicate check then? If you are concerned with reading/writing speed of large datasets, you should take a look at non-base packages that are made to deal with big datasets.

Answer (score 1):

```
> # Original Setup ----------------------------------------------------------
> df1 <- data.frame(name = c('a','b','c'), a = c(1,2,2))
> write.csv(df1, "export.csv", row.names=FALSE, na="NA"); 
> 
> # Add Some Data -----------------------------------------------------------
> df1[,1]  <- as.character(df1[,1])
> df1[,2]  <- as.numeric(df1[,2])
> df1[4,1] <- 'd'
> df1[4,2] <- 3
> 
> # Have a Look at It -------------------------------------------------------
> head(df1)
  name a
1    a 1
2    b 2
3    c 2
4    d 3
> 
> # Write It Out Without Duplication ----------------------------------------
> write.table(df1, "export.csv", row.names=F, na="NA", 
+             append = F, quote= FALSE, sep = ",", col.names = T)
> 
> # Proof It Works ----------------------------------------------------------
> proof <- read.csv("export.csv")
> head(proof)
  name a
1    a 1
2    b 2
3    c 2
4    d 3
```

You could alternately follow the comment on your question that recommended `rbind` or simply use `write.csv` or `write.table` with and `append = T` option, making sure to properly handle row and column names.

However, I will also recommend using and `readRDS` and `saveRDS` and just overwriting the `rds` objects rather than appending as a best practice. The use of `RDS` is recommended by Hadley and other top names in R.